# Earth Engine Feature Collection to Image doesn't return values (can't work with Image)

Tags: google-earth-engine, jupyter-notebook

I have a bunch of Polygons and build a Feature Collection out of them.

For testing the only property of each Feature is "Code" with the value 3:

```
import ee
import geopandas as gpd
ee.Initialize()
from geomet import wkt
from IPython.display import Image
import json

features = ee.List([])

x = 0
for i in range(0,len(gpd_frame)):
    g = wkt.loads(gpd_frame["geometry"][i].to_wkt())        #this part is for getting the geometry of the feature out of a dataframe
    fet = ee.Feature(g,{"Code":ee.Number(3)})
    features = features.add(fet)
    x = x+1
    if x > 500:                                                                #for testing
        break

col = ee.FeatureCollection(features)                              #FeatureCollection from list features



imgFC = col.reduceToImage(["Code"],"first")


imgFC.getInfo()


{'type': 'Image',
 'bands': [{'id': 'first',
   'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType',
    'precision': 'int',
    'min': -9223372036854775808,
    'max': 9223372036854775807},
   'crs': 'EPSG:4326',
   'crs_transform': [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]}]}
```

If I now want to look on the values with:

```
values = imgFC.select("first").reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.toList(),geometry=gebiet,maxPixels=1e8,scale=10).getInfo()
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EEException                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-a69761c0332a> in <module>()
----> 1 values = imgFC.select("first").reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.toList(),geometry=gebiet,maxPixels=1e8,scale=10).getInfo()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ee\computedobject.py in getInfo(self)
     93       The object can evaluate to anything.
     94     """
---> 95     return data.computeValue(self)
     96 
     97   def encode(self, encoder):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py in computeValue(obj)
    488     The result of evaluating that object on the server.
    489   """
--> 490   return send_('/value', ({'json': obj.serialize(), 'json_format': 'v2'}))
    491 
    492 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py in send_(path, params, opt_method, opt_raw)
   1184       raise ee_exception.EEException('Invalid JSON: %s' % content)
   1185     if 'error' in json_content:
-> 1186       raise ee_exception.EEException(json_content['error']['message'])
   1187     if 'data' not in content:
   1188       raise ee_exception.EEException('Malformed response: ' + str(content))

EEException: An internal server error has occurred (ecbf2f1b7ee629dde4a2080f8856209a).
```

Has anyone an idea to solve this or another way to add features/polygons with values (later with different values for "Code") to another image?
As result the Image should have a band with the values of the features.